# Find count of value in dictionary keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary lets call dict. The keys are numbers, and the values are either 'A' or 'B' and I'm trying to find the number of times 'B' is a value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`list.count` provides one way:

```
d = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'A', 6: 'B'}

list(d.values()).count('B')  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter` for that.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'foo': 'A', 'bar': 'A'}

count = Counter(d.values())

count['A'] # 2
```